# How to add number of days in postgresql datetime

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have the following table `projects`.

```
id title        created_at               claim_window
1  Project One  2012-05-08 13:50:09.924  5
2  Project Two  2012-06-01 13:50:09.924  10
```

A) I want to find the deadline with the calculation `deadline = created_at + claim_window`, where `claim_window` is the number of days. Something like following:

```
id title        created_at               claim_window  deadline
1  Project One  2012-05-08 13:50:09.924  5             2012-05-13 13:50:09.924
2  Project Two  2012-06-01 13:50:09.924  10            2012-06-11 13:50:09.924
```

B) I also want to find the projects whose deadline is gone:

```
id title        created_at               claim_window  deadline
1  Project One  2012-05-08 13:50:09.924  5             2012-05-13 13:50:09.924
```

I tried something like following, but it didn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM "projects" 
WHERE (DATE_PART('day', now()- created_at) >= (claim_window+1))
```

Answer (score 212, accepted):

This will give you the deadline :

```
select id,  
       title,
       created_at + interval '1' day * claim_window as deadline
from projects
```

Alternatively the function `make_interval` can be used:

```
select id,  
       title,
       created_at + make_interval(days => claim_window) as deadline
from projects
```

To get all projects where the deadline is over, use:

```
select *
from (
  select id, 
         created_at + interval '1' day * claim_window as deadline
  from projects
) t
where localtimestamp at time zone 'UTC' > deadline
```

Comment: but one more issue is occur my created_at has datatype `timestamp without time zone` AND current_timestamp has datatype `timestamp with time zone`, hence i don't get correct answer

Comment: @Salil: `LOCALTIMESTAMP` is a `timestamp without time zone`

Comment: @Salil: It also does not matter, the result would be the same with either `timestamp` or `timestamptz`, as long as the data is referring to the same point in time. Adding a day has the same effect on both.

Comment: my create_at is get saved in the UTC time (W/o timezone) and LOCALTIMESTAMP & CURRENT_TIMESTAMP gives me time in the +5.30, hence probles is still not get solved

Comment: @Salil: then re-calculate the localtimestamp to utc using `localtimestamp at time zone 'UTC'`

Comment: I would rewrite that query like this:
    `with t as
    (
      select id
           , created_at + interval '1' day * claim_window as deadline
      from projects
    )
    select *
    from t
    where localtimestamp at time zone 'UTC' > deadline`

Answer (score 34):

For me I had to put the whole interval in single quotes not just the value of the interval.

```
select id,  
   title,
   created_at + interval '1 day' * claim_window as deadline from projects
```

Instead of

```
select id,  
   title,
   created_at + interval '1' day * claim_window as deadline from projects
```

[Postgres Date/Time Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: created_at + '1 day' worked for me as well.

Answer (score 8):

you can just use the below code to append or substract any date field

```
select date('08/30/2021') + 180  ---it will give next 180 days date

select current_date + 180  ---it will give next 180 days date

select current_date - 180  ---it will give before 180 days date
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this if you need to add the number of days to the timestamp: `SELECT (now() + (:count_days * INTERVAL '1 days'))::timestamp;`