# How to add a variable number of hours to a date in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

[Apparently](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL), PostgreSQL doesn't have `DATEADD`, because you can just use the `+` or `-` operators.

I need to add a number of hours to a date, which is accomplished like this:

```
date_field + interval '8.25 hour'
```

Which is great, but I need the number of hours to come from a field in the table. Would be something like this:

```
date_field + interval start_time 'hour'
```

I can't find anywhere how to do this. Is this actually impossible?

I don't mind resorting to ugly hacks like taking the field value and dividing by 3600, multiplying by 86400. Whatever I need to do, but I haven't found any way to do that either.

Answer (score 126):

To add *hours*:

```
SELECT date_field + interval '1 hour' * start_time;
```

[`interval` can be multiplied by a scalar.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE)
`start_time` can be any numerical value.
`'1 hour'` can be shortened to `'1h'`.

If `date_field` is data type ...
... `timestamp without time zone` (= `timestamp`) or `date`, the result is `timestamp`.
... `timestamp with time zone` (= `timestamptz`), the result is `timestamptz`.

Comment: Erwin Brandstetter strikes again :) Awesome answer

Answer (score 10):

Found the answer, [in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909902/how-to-add-number-of-days-in-postgresql-datetime):

```
date + interval '1' minute * FLOOR(start_time * 60)
```

Hope that helps anyone

Answer (score 6):

The one worked for me is

```
SELECT date_field + interval '1' HOUR * start_time
```

**start_time** can be any numerical value.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone wants to add in time stamp then

```
select time '05:00' - interval '2 hours'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `make_interval()`

```
date_field + make_interval(hours => start_time)
```