# How can I update the time in a column without affecting the date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

In my database I have this column of type `DATE` with a lot of dates stored in it. I converted it to `DATETIME` using timestamptz. But the time is 00:00:00.

I want to change all the time to be 09:00:00 i tried a lot with update and set but I just get errors.

```
UPDATE note
SET entered = entered + TIMESTAMP(DATE(entered), TIME('09:00:00');
```

The error message was the following:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DATE" LINE 2: SET entered = entered +
> TIMESTAMP(DATE(entered), TIME('09:00...
> ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 47

Can anyone help me change the time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a variable number of hours to a date in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160207/how-to-add-a-variable-number-of-hours-to-a-date-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try truncating all timestamps to midnight, then adding 9 hours:

```sql
UPDATE note
SET entered = DATE_TRUNC('day', entered) + interval '9' hour;
```

Comment: An alternative to Tim's query: `UPDATE note SET entered = entered::date + '09:00:00'::time;` +1

Comment: @HayyanMotsu so accept the answer ;)

Comment: @JimJones Your version even looks more canonical than mine.

Comment: @JimJones i can't, i have to wait 10 minutes at least before i can click the button

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen well, but you were faster :-D and your solution works too ;) cheers

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding a time interval, like so

```
UPDATE note
SET entered = enetered + interval '9 hours';
```

Comment: Wouldn't this update **add** 9 hours to the timestamp instead of changing its time? ;)

Comment: @JimJones Yes, you are right, it does add 9 hours, but in this case, with all values having time = '00:00:00', you can achieve the same result without additional format conversions. The accepted answer is a more general solution

Answer (score 0):

## for ms sql

#try this instead

UPDATE note
SET entered = convert(nvarchar,entered,23)+' '+convert(nvarchar,'09:00:00')

Comment: UPDATE note SET entered = convert(nvarchar,entered,23) + ' '+convert(nvarchar,'09:00:00')

Comment: But the question is for Postgres. You are answering a question that hasn’t been asked here.