# Generate SQL for datetime in loop

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Here I want to print dates in a loop.

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE counter INTEGER := 0 ; 
DECLARE interval_days TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
   WHILE counter <= 5 LOOP
      counter := counter + 1 ; 
      interval_days := NOW() - INTERVAL '2 DAY';
      RAISE NOTICE '%', interval_days;
   END LOOP ; 
END; $$
```

In the above code, I want to print something like this.

2020-11-16 12:11:43.741087
2020-11-15 12:11:43.741087
2020-11-14 12:11:43.741087
Date in different days interval. 2 days is not fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add number of days in postgresql datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909902/how-to-add-number-of-days-in-postgresql-datetime)

Comment: Why not just use `select * from generate_series(current_timestamp - interval '5 day', current_timestamp, interval '1' day)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify your code slightly:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
   counter INTEGER := 0; 
   interval_days TIMESTAMP := current_timestamp;
BEGIN
   WHILE counter <= 5 LOOP
      counter := counter + 1; 
      interval_days := interval_days - INTERVAL '1 DAY';
      RAISE NOTICE '%', interval_days;
   END LOOP; 
END;$$;
```

But you can get the same with

```
SELECT *
FROM generate_series(
        current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 DAY',
        current_timestamp - INTERVAL '6 DAY',
        INTERVAL '-1 DAY'
     );
```

Comment: Thanks, Laurenz, a_horse_with_no_name I got a solution. But my problem was the number is not in series. where counter can be any other number noo need to be in a series.

Comment: @codebuzzz What is "other" number, when in your code you increment with the same number of days? If you generate a random number somewhere inbetween and need to convert integer to interval, then use, for example, `make_interval(days := <num_days>)` or `interval '1 day'*<number>`, as I suggested you the answer in comment to the question.

Comment: @astentx The question was not quite clear about this. I interpreted that the interval could change, but would always be the same for one query. In that case you'd just change the interval in my code, for example using a function. If the interval varies withing a single query, one would need a description of where that information comes from.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Exactly, and that was my assumption too. That's why I've asked the OP how to get those numbers so your answer can be accepted or improved.

Comment: @astentx Anyway, it looks like this question is abandoned. Let's just close it.